# Normal Abelian Subgroup does not imply Abelian Quotient Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups

I'm a bit confused and just need some clarification about what I am missing in this:

I have $S_4$ with normal subgroup $N=\lbrace(),(1,2)(3,4),(1,3)(2,4),(1,4)(2,3)\rbrace$.

I know that $N$ is normal (and abelian), which means $gN=Ng, \forall g\in G$, so to me, by definition of a quotient group it follows that $\frac{G}{N}=\lbrace gN:g\in G\rbrace=\lbrace Ng:g\in G\rbrace$, which suggests that $\frac{G}{N}$ is abelian, however I know this is wrong because $\frac{G}{N}\cong D_6$ which isn't abelian.

So just wondering what step I am misunderstanding, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recall that the group operation on $\frac{G}{N}$ is $(g_1N)(g_2N) = g_1g_2N$ if you use left cosets or $(Ng_1)(Ng_2) = Ng_1g_2$ if you use right cosets. Knowing that $gN = Ng$ does not imply $g_1g_2N = g_2g_1N$ but rather that $g_1g_2N = Ng_1g_2$.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks for clearing that up. So then, I know $G$ abelian $\Rightarrow$ all subgroups are normal, which would mean that $g_1g_2N=g_2g_1N$ thus all quotient groups of an abelian group are abelian?

Comment: You are correct.